# Get TFS mapped folder of a local sub folder of the solution?

Tags: c#, tfs, mapping, directory, source-control-explorer

Let's say we have a solution in TFS Source Control which has already been mapped to a local folder `SolutionFolder`.

We are in a sub folder `SubFolder` of this `SolutionFolder`. 
How can we write C# code to get the mapped path of this `SubFolder`?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `WorkStation.Current` to grab the information for the folder in question:

Import the following namespaces:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
```

and then use you can get to the data you want through:

```
var workspace = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(solutionFolder);
if (workspace != null)
{
    var teamProjectUri = workspace.ServerUri;

    // var server = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(teamProjectUri);
    var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(teamProjectUri);   
    var cssService = projectCollection.GetService<ICommonStructureService4>();
    var project = cssService.GetProjectFromName(solutionName);
}
```

From there you can easily grab the Workspace as well and from there the serverpath: [`workspace.GetWorkspace().GetServerItemForLocalItem()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.getserveritemforlocalitem.aspx)

To provide credentials, you can use one of the additional overloads that accepts a `CredentialsProvider`. The default provider is the [`UICredentialsProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.uicredentialsprovider.aspx). Or you can also call `server` or `projectCollection`'s [`EnsureAuthenticated`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/280f00b7-5f7b-4330-aa64-3b1625ca6096/when-to-use-tfsteamprojectcollectionensureauthenticated?forum=tfsworkitemtracking).

See also:

- https://jessehouwing.net/vsts-tfs-api-auto-detect-connection-details/

Comment: Where do we put in the tfs server, login username and password?

Comment: The TFS Server is automatically retrieved based on the Workspace settings. The location is stored in the registry.